# Не выводится текст при отправке email через python

Tags: python, email

Использую модуль `smtplib` для того что бы отправлять информацию самому себе через  email.

Код:

```
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('мой email','Вы думали , что покажу?')                 
smtpObj.sendmail("мой email","мой email","Camera: Verified unknown!!")
smtpObj.quit()
```

Отправляется пустое сообщение:

[image: Скриншот сообщения]

**Почему** не выводится содержимое сообщения (или почему вообще не отправляется содержимое сообщения) и **как** это решить?

Comment: Я так и не понимаю , почему вопрос заминусовали и хотят закрыть?

Comment: А почему этот способ не работает?